# Threaded TCP server-trying to maintain data consistency of a User Repository

Tags: java, multithreading, tcp, synchronization

So I have a TCP server which has the ability for clients to register users.It contains a UserRepo object which holds the registered users and handles the adding of users.How do I make it that even with multiple clients accessing my server on different threads that the data for UserRepo remains consistent and correct across all threads?

Server.java

```
  package danielhaughtonemailapplicationca1;


 import java.io.*;
 import java.net.*;

class Server implements Runnable
{
Socket connectionSocket;
   UserRepo userRepo;
public Server(Socket s){
    try{
        System.out.println("Client Got Connected  " );
        connectionSocket=s;
                    userRepo = new UserRepo();
    }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
}

public void run(){
    try{
                User loggedInUser = null;
                String input="";
                while(!"exit".equals(input)){

            BufferedReader reader =
                    new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));
            BufferedWriter writer= 
                    new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(connectionSocket.getOutputStream()));
                   if(loggedInUser == null){
                       loginOrRegister(reader,writer,input);
                   }else{

                   }

                }
                System.out.println("A connection was closed");
                connectionSocket.close();
    }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
   }
    public  void loginOrRegister(BufferedReader reader,BufferedWriter writer,String input) throws IOException{
                        while(input.equals("exit")){
        writer.write("*** Hi!Write login to login or register to register ***\r\n");            
            writer.flush();
            input = reader.readLine().trim();
                    if(input.equals("register")){
                     writer.write("*** write the email address you want ***\r\n");            
            writer.flush();
                        String email = reader.readLine().trim();
                                                 writer.write("*** write the password you want ***\r\n");            
            writer.flush();
                        String password = reader.readLine().trim();
                        User user = userRepo.addUser(email, password);
                    }else if(input.equals("login")){

                    }

    }
    }

 public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception
  {
     System.out.println("Threaded Server is Running  " );
     ServerSocket mysocket = new ServerSocket(5555);
     while(true)
     {
        Socket sock = mysocket.accept();
        Server server=new Server(sock);

        Thread serverThread=new Thread(server);
        serverThread.start();

     }
  }
  }
```

UserRepo

```
public class UserRepo {
ArrayList<User> registeredUsers;

public UserRepo() {
}

public UserRepo(ArrayList<User> registeredUsers) {
    this.registeredUsers = registeredUsers;
}
public ArrayList<User> getRegisteredUsers() {
    return registeredUsers;
}
public void setRegisteredUsers(ArrayList<User> registeredUsers) {
    this.registeredUsers = registeredUsers;
}

public User addUser(String email,String password){
    for(int i=0;i<=registeredUsers.size();i++){
        if(registeredUsers.get(i).getEmail().equalsIgnoreCase("email")){
            //if the email already exists,return null,we cant add the user
            return null;
        }
    }
    //if we get here the user can be added
    User user = new User(email,password);
        registeredUsers.add(user);
        return user;
}
public User login(String email,String password){
            for(int i=0;i<=registeredUsers.size();i++){
        if(registeredUsers.get(i).getEmail().equalsIgnoreCase("email")){
           //here we found the user with the given email
           //lets check if the password is right
            if(password.equals(registeredUsers.get(i).getPassword())){
                //password is right
                return registeredUsers.get(i);
            }else{
                //the password isnt correct
                return null;
            }
        }
 }
            //we get here if we didnt find a matching email,return null
            return null;
 }
 }
```

Comment: Don't keep creating readers and writers inside the loop. You will lose data. Create them ahead of the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the most basic synchronization mechanism in Java is the use of `synchronized`, either as a method modifier [1] (i.e. `public synchronized User addUser(String email,String password)` or as a statement [2].

Of course, the smaller the synchronized block (whether as a statement or as a function), the less performance you have to trade since other threads will block (be waiting) for a smaller number of instructions.

In this case, you could do something like:

```
synchronized(this) {
    registeredUsers.add(user);
}
```

This would make Thread `A` acquire a lock on the `registeredUsers`. When Thread `B` tries to add a new user while another is being added, Thread `B` would wait until it can acquire the lock from Thread `A` (in this case, as soon as Thread `A`'s execution leaves the `synchronized` block).

See also the references below.

[1] https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html

[2] https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html